# When using HAML in my Rails app to list all items in a table, I get a strange dump as well. This does not happen with erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I know the title of this question might be strange, but that was the best way I could explain it in words. Here is the case:

I have made a simple Rails app which has a table called "Teams". There are entries in this table which I want to iterate through and list the names of all the teams. Here is the code I have written for my controller and my view:

**teams_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @teams = Team.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
  end
end
```

**index.html.haml**

```
%h3
  Listing teams

= @teams.each do |team|
  %p= link_to team.name, team

%p= link_to 'Add new team', new_team_path
```

The output correctly iterates through all the teams, but then also throws out a strange dump of the entire contents of @teams. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

The kicker is, previously when I had this written out using the default erb standard, it was all good. I decided to use haml instead, and this seems to be the only problem that has popped-up and I can't figure out for the life of me why it is.

Would love some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `=` on the beginning of `each` line (line 4) and replace it with `-`. You're outputting the return of each (which is every row).

Like this:

```
%h3
  Listing teams

- @teams.each do |team|
  %p= link_to team.name, team

%p= link_to 'Add new team', new_team_path
```

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick! Coming from erb, I wasn't aware this is how I should execute Ruby code without printing it out.

Comment: erb used to have `-`, but was deprecated. This, in erb, essentially means "do not output this line", which is what happened (a blank line) if you left the `-` out. HAML was created around that time, and used this as a syntax to run ruby, but not output its contents.